# Dynamic Preamble Content doesn't seem to work in mylatexformat Precompilation

Tags: mylatexformat

TLDR: Nothing past `\csname endofdump\endcsname` can be built before the \begin{document} in the main file.

Reference: https://bitbucket.org/johannesjh/latex-precompiled-preamble-example/src/master/

When cloning and compiling https://bitbucket.org/johannesjh/latex-precompiled-preamble-example/src/master/ exactly as instructed, nothing in the `preamble-dynamic` is passed through for compilation.

E.g. if you add a simple:

`\def \test {test}`

To the `preamble-dynamic.tex` and then build:

```
%&preamble
\include{preamble-dynamic}

\begin{document}
This file uses the pre-compiled preamble

Test this URL \url{http://google.com}.

\test

\end{document}
```

For the thesis it returns the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \test
```

If you remove the first line from the thesis.tex file, `%&preamble` (and the url since the package is loaded in the static preamble), the def builds no problem.

Same problem if we add the \def after the endofdump:

```
% static preamble
\include{preamble-static}
\csname endofdump\endcsname

\def \test {test}
% dynamic preamble
% note: not really needed because the sole purpose of this file is to compile the static preamble.
\include{preamble-dynamic}
\usepackage{verbatim}
```

In the precompile.tex file; cannot pick it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to resolve this, you need an \endofdump in the main.tex file as well, so:

```
%&preamble
\endofdump
\include{preamble-dynamic}

\begin{document}
This file uses the pre-compiled preamble

Test this URL \url{http://google.com}.

\test

\end{document}
```

Resolves the issue